# Unable to login using the valid credentials with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have configured the spring security in my project but each time I'm trying to login with correct credentials, I am unable to login. Console is displaying the mesage that salt source is not found. Why it is trying to find the getId in userAwareUserDetails? I have separate user class

2015-04-30 10:44:03 DEBUG ConnectionManager:302 - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
  **2015-04-30 10:44:03 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:346 - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Unable to find salt method on user Object. Does the class 'com.spring.security.UserAwareUserDetails' have a method or getter named 'getId' ?**
  2015-04-30 10:44:03 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:347 - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
  2015-04-30 10:44:03 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:348 - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@6f12ac99
  2015-04-30 10:44:03 DEBUG SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler:67 - Redirecting to /login?action=authFail
  2015-04-30 10:44:03 DEBUG DefaultRedirectStrategy:36 - Redirecting to '/spring3batchjobliquibasetestngspringsecurityproject/login?action=authFail'
  2015-04-30 10:44:03 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:269 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
  2015-04-30 10:44:03 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
  2015-04-30 10:44:03 DEBUG OpenSessionInViewFilter:207 - Closing single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
  2015-04-30 10:44:03 DEBUG SessionFactoryUtils:800 - Closing Hibernate Session

**In applicationContext.xml** Below is the configuration :

```
    <import resource="classpath:resources/spring-security.xml" /> 
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        ........................
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        ....................
    </bean> 
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                .......
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="connection.autocommit">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">createOrUpdate</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.FlushMode">AUTO</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>
                <prop key="connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

**As clear from above I'm importing the spring-security.xml in applicationContext**

**In spring-security.xml** Below is the configuration

```
<!-- Scan for spring annotated components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <http pattern="/assets/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/login" security="none"/>
    <!-- HTTP basic authentication in Spring Security -->
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_API" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**"  access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/login?action=authFail"/>

        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/userAdmin" authentication-failure-url="/login?action=authFail" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout=loginFail"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
                <salt-source ref="saltSource"/>
            </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder"/>

    <beans:bean id="saltSource" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
        <beans:property name="userPropertyToUse">
            <beans:value>getId</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

I have custom userserviceDetailImpl where i have overriden the loadUserByUsername method.

**Below is the User class**

```
public class User {
 private Long id = new Long(-1L);
..............................
 public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public boolean isPersistent() {
        return version != null;
    }
...............
............
}
```

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved now, By adding the getter method in userawareuserdetails class the problem is resolved.